# issues deploying laravel 4 on windows shared hosting server

Tags: php, laravel

I use apache and php 5.5 on my local windows machine to develop my laravel site, but when i try to upload to my client's hosting account (which is windows-IIs shared hosting account), i get this error below. Please what could be the problem and what's the solution.

Please note that I don't have write access to the root folder of the hosting account, it's only the httpdocs folder(which is located in the root folder along with some other folders)  that i have write access to.

```
"Error in exception handler: The stream or file
"C:\Inetpub\vhosts\systetech.com\httpdocs\app\storage/logs/laravel.log" 
could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied in      
C:\Inetpub\vhosts\systetech.com\httpdocs\vendor\monolog\monolog\src\Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler.php:84"
```

Comment: Could you post the code that gives you the error?  Also I noticed a couple forward slashes, mixed into the path, that may be causing trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Storage` directory doesn't have the right permissions on it. I know in Linux you have to do `chmod -R 777 app/storage` to allow access to it, so do the same to that directory on Windows.

This error isn't caused by any code in particular. When navigating to the URL of a Laravel application that doesn't have `storage` permissions set right, the application with die and give you that error. I don't know how you configure permissions on a windows machine (I develop on Linux) but I know you have to set `app/storage/` to writable before you can 'run' the application.